# Train error with lm model: Unused arguments

Tags: r, model, linear-regression, prediction, training-data

I am trying to create a multiple linear regression model, because I need to predict the number of Travelers in a series. When applying the train function I get the following error::

> "Error in train(Viajeros ~ ., data = frm, method = "lm", trControl =
> trainControl) :    unused arguments (data = frm, method = "lm",
> trControl = trainControl)".

**The code is:**

```
# Regresión lineal múltiple
trainControl <- trainControl(
                             method="cv", 
                             number=3, 
                             classProbs=TRUE,
                             summaryFunction=twoClassSummary
                           )
frm <- as.formula(paste("Viajeros ~ ", paste(relevant_features, collapse="+")))

set.seed(7)
fit <- train( 
             Viajeros~., 
             data = frm, 
             method="lm", 
             trControl=trainControl
            )
```

**and the data is distributed as follows:**
[image]

I don't know what's wrong, but it won't let me apply any kind of model. I always get the same error.

Comment: Perhaps try specifying what packages you're using, too.

Comment: train() comes from the caret package. @Marta López Gómez: it's always good to create a small reproducible example, which includes the library and some data.

Answer (score 1):

You must use `glm` instead of `lm` in caret to get it worked for binary classifcation. Then you can use a formula and a data frame like this:

```r
library(caret)
#> Loading required package: lattice
#> Loading required package: ggplot2
library(tidyverse)

data <- iris %>% mutate(is_setosa = ifelse(Species == "setosa", "setosa", "other") %>% factor())

trainControl <- trainControl(
  method="cv", 
  number=3, 
  classProbs=TRUE,
  summaryFunction=twoClassSummary
)

frm <- is_setosa ~ Sepal.Length + Petal.Length

set.seed(7)
fit <- train( 
  form = frm,
  data = data,
  method="glm", 
  trControl=trainControl
)
#> Warning in train.default(x, y, weights = w, ...): The metric "Accuracy" was not
#> in the result set. ROC will be used instead.
#> Warning: glm.fit: algorithm did not converge
#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred
#> Warning: glm.fit: algorithm did not converge
#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred
#> Warning: glm.fit: algorithm did not converge
#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred
#> Warning: glm.fit: algorithm did not converge
#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You need to correctly specify the `formula` and `data` arguments (formula should not be a `data.frame`, but a formula, and vice versa).

```
library(caret)

# Regresión lineal múltiple
trainControl <- trainControl(
  method="cv", 
  number=3, 
  classProbs=TRUE,
  #summaryFunction=twoClassSummary # does not work with lm
)

frm <- as.formula(paste("Viajeros ~ ", paste(relevant_features, collapse="+")))

set.seed(7)
fit <- train( 
  form = frm, 
  data = data, 
  method="lm", 
  trControl=trainControl
)
```

Comment: In caret `lm` does not allow the use of `twoClassSummary`. Please run your code e.g. using the package `reprex` to ensure it is right.

Comment: Just fixed it, but your answer is more complete with actual data, just upvoted it. I was just too lazy to create a minimal reproducible example in the answer..